# Pass the props from grandchild to parent without exporting in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a button component (grandchild) that has an exported prop (as follows)

```
<script>
    export let buttonText = "";
</script>

<button>
    {buttonText}
</button>
```

In the **component** I import this button. But I don't want to pass the data to the prop here.

```
<script>
import Button from './Button.svelte';
</script>

<h1>
    Hello from the component
    <br>
    <Button buttonText=""/>
</h1>
```

***Note**: that I have not exported the buttonText from the component*

I want to call the **component** from the parent and pass the data to **buttonText**

```
<script>
    import Component from './Component.svelte'
</script>

<Component buttonText="Hello"/>
```

Can I do it without exporting?

The reason I wanted to do it, I have many subcomponents such as buttons, forms etc being imported into the component. I already some props exported from the component itself. By exporting the props of subcomponents, I would end up having a big mess of exports including duplication as well.

**If this is not possible, is there any better way?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use setContext to set or get data from a parent with setContext to a child or a child from a child et cetera with getContext. First the basics:

**parent:**

```js
import { setContext } from "svelte"; 
    
let btnTxt = "Button Text";
setContext("getBtnTxt", btnTxt"}
```

**grandchild**

```js
import { getContext } from "svelte";

let btnTxt = getContext("getBtnTxt")
```

But the are other ways to set and get data from the parent.

**Example set and get parent data:**

```js
const ctxFilters = { a: false, b: false, c: false };
setContext("ctxFilters", {
  get filters() {
    return ctxFilters;
  },
  set filters(obj) {
    Object.assign(ctxFilters, obj);
  },
});
```

and in a child / childs or grandchilds:

```js
const filterCtx = getContext("ctxFilters");
let filters = filterCtx.filters;  // use the getter
...
filterCtx.filters = filters;  // or use the setter
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use svelte slots for that like so:

**grandchild**

```
<button>
  <slot />
</button>
```

**parent**

```
<h1>
  Hello from the component
  <br />
  <Button>
    <slot name="btn-text" />
  </Button>
</h1>
```

**grandparent**

```
<Component>
  <svelte:fragment slot="btn-text">Hello</svelte:fragment>
</Component>
```